# How do I fix a broken git revision that has no ident?

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I have a git repository with lots of revisions. I'm the only developer, so all commits are from me so far. Somehow, I ended up with a single commit that has no ident information. I tried running:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
>> GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=myusername
>> GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=myuseremail@website.com
>> export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
>> export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
rewrite deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef (112/123)fatal: empty ident name (for ()) not allowed
could not write rewritten commit
rm: cannot remove '/c/some/directory/that/leads/to/my/repository/.git-rewrite/revs': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory '/c/some/directory/that/leads/to/my/repository/.git-rewrite': Directory is empty
```

what am I doing wrong? Everything I see online about ident tells you how to fix commits before you make them: what do you do *after* the commit is already through?

Comment: I don't know if this can be of help, but have you checked the last section of this page: [git-book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)? It talks about changing the e-mail after commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure, I would set AUTHOR *and* COMMITTER, and use [`git commit-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree), to record the change.

You can see a full example in "[Change the author of a commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870367/6309)".

Note: to reset your filter-branch, you might have to:

- exit your git bash
- delete the `.git-rewrite` folder.